# Syntax of NOT IN usage of LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a System.Data.Entity.Dbset provided to me by the DataContext of EntityFramework.
I have an ObservableCollection AllTaxes in my ViewModel
i simply want to delete all those entries from System.Data.Entity.Dbset which have been deleted from AllTaxes,based on a common property called "TaxCode" using Linq.

I m not very good with Linq.I used the following Linq to find out all TaxCodes deleted from ViewModel but still existing in Model.

```
var List = Hexa_entity.hexa_tax.Where(Left => !AllTaxes.Any(Right => Right.TaxCode == Left.TaxCode));
```

However,this is giving me the exception:-

> Unable to create a constant value of type `Hexa.Models.DM_Tax`. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Simply put ,How do i convert the SQL query in between to linq?

```
List<ClassTest> Lst = 
    select * from List1<ClassTest>() 
    where id not in (select id from List2<ClassTest>())
    .ToList<ClassTest>();
```

Comment: What is the type of property named 'TaxCode'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix that issue try the following:

```
var AllTaxesCodes=AllTaxes.Select(e=>e.TaxCode);//Use a collection of primitive type
var List = Hexa_entity.hexa_tax.Where(Left => !AllTaxesCodes.Contains( Left.TaxCode));
```

Comment: you're wecome ;)